# Spring Couchbase Repository does not save data in JUnit 5 BeforeEach method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE, and tried to use JUnit 5 to test Repository.

Spring Boot application config for couchbase.

```
spring:
  couchbase:
    bootstrap-hosts: localhost
    bucket:
      name: default
      password: password
  data:
    couchbase:
      auto-index: true
```

I use a Docker compose to start up a Couchbase in Docker, it run the latest 6.0 at the moment.

```
version: '3.3' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:

  couchbase:
    image: couchbase
    ports:
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8092:8092"
      - "8093:8093"
      - "8094:8094"
      - "11210:11210"
    volumes:
      - couchbasedata:/opt/couchbase/var
volumes:
    couchbasedata:
```

The document used in the project.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
@Builder
public class Assignment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;

    //private int index;
    private String roomNumber;
    private String assignee;
    @Builder.Default
    private Status currentStatus = Status.PENDING;

}
```

And the Repository for Assignment.

```
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "assignment", viewName = "all")
public interface AssignmentRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Assignment, String> {

    List<Assignment> findAll();
}
```

And test codes for Repository.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class AssignmentRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private AssignmentRepository assignmentRepository;


    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        log.debug("before each:::");
        this.assignmentRepository.deleteAll();


        Assignment assignment = Assignment.builder().assignee("Tom").roomNumber("101").build();
        Assignment assignment2 = Assignment.builder().assignee("Tom").roomNumber("102").build();

        this.assignmentRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(assignment, assignment2));

        log.debug("saved assignments: {}", this.assignmentRepository.findAll());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach() {
        log.debug("after each:::");
        this.assignmentRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAll() {
        List<Assignment> assignments = this.assignmentRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(2, assignments.size());
    }

}
```

When I run this test, it fails. I find the `saveAll` dese not work as expected, the `log.debug("saved assignments: {}", this.assignmentRepository.findAll());` prints an empty List.

```
2019-02-28 09:01:57.865 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] c.example.demo.AssignmentRepositoryTest  : before each:::
2019-02-28 09:01:58.128 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] d.c.c.m.e.AbstractCouchbaseEventListener : onBeforeConvert(Assignment(id=null, roomNumber=101, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING))
2019-02-28 09:01:58.174 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] c.c.m.e.ValidatingCouchbaseEventListener : Validating object: Assignment(id=null, roomNumber=101, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING)
2019-02-28 09:01:58.456 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] d.c.c.m.e.AbstractCouchbaseEventListener : onAfterSave(Assignment(id=fbedcace-c6db-45db-a788-9aa688b0a068, roomNumber=101, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING), CouchbaseDocument{id=fbedcace-c6db-45db-a788-9aa688b0a068, exp=0, payload={roomNumber=101, currentStatus=PENDING, _class=com.example.demo.domain.Assignment, assignee=Tom}})
2019-02-28 09:01:58.457 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] d.c.c.m.e.AbstractCouchbaseEventListener : onBeforeConvert(Assignment(id=null, roomNumber=102, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING))
2019-02-28 09:01:58.457 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] c.c.m.e.ValidatingCouchbaseEventListener : Validating object: Assignment(id=null, roomNumber=102, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING)
2019-02-28 09:01:58.461 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] d.c.c.m.e.AbstractCouchbaseEventListener : onAfterSave(Assignment(id=5cdf11e1-f50f-47f0-acfd-a31f0b4970be, roomNumber=102, assignee=Tom, currentStatus=PENDING), CouchbaseDocument{id=5cdf11e1-f50f-47f0-acfd-a31f0b4970be, exp=0, payload={roomNumber=102, currentStatus=PENDING, _class=com.example.demo.domain.Assignment, assignee=Tom}})
2019-02-28 09:02:04.723 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] c.example.demo.AssignmentRepositoryTest  : saved assignments: []
2019-02-28 09:02:04.790 DEBUG 16608 --- [           main] c.example.demo.AssignmentRepositoryTest  : after each:::
```

**Updated**: I added `@TestConfiguration`as suggested in the test package, and imported it in test class, unluckily it still does not work as expected.

```
@TestConfiguration
@Slf4j
@Order(0)
public class TestCouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Override
    public IndexManager indexManager() {
        return new IndexManager(true, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts").split(","));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.name");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.password");
    }

    @Override
    protected Consistency getDefaultConsistency() {
        return Consistency.STRONGLY_CONSISTENT; //READ_YOUR_OWN_WRITES|UPDATE_AFTER ... etc;
    }
}
```

I have created a sample project to reproduce the problem I encountered, check out it from [my Github](https://github.com/hantsy/data-couchbase-issue).

Comment: Could you please add a breakpoint on this line "log.debug("saved assignments: {}", this.assignmentRepository.findAll());" and check if the value of this.assignmentRepository.findAll() ? Views are eventually consistent, your findAll might be running before the view is updated.

Comment: @deniswsrosa How to fix this in JUnit? I have tried using a `CommandLineRunner` to load some data in application startup phase, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Views are eventually consistent by default in Couchbase.

Here is the doc about it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.consistency

You can change the default behavior by defining a Java config class:

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Override
    public IndexManager indexManager() {
        return new IndexManager(true, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts").split(","));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketName() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.name");
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBucketPassword() {
        return env.getProperty("spring.couchbase.bucket.password");
    }

    @Override
    protected Consistency getDefaultConsistency() {
    return Consistency.STRONGLY_CONSISTENT//READ_YOUR_OWN_WRITES|UPDATE_AFTER ... etc;
    }
}
```

PS: As you might guess, STRONGLY_CONSISTENT is not as fast as the default one, so if you need max performance, I recommend you to enable STRONGLY_CONSISTENT only during tests.

PS2: Operations by the key are always strong consistent (findById, Save, update, etc)

Comment: I added a standalone `@TestConfiguration` class as you suggested, and imported in the test class, it still does not work.

Comment: Added a link to [the sample project](https://github.com/hantsy/data-couchbase-issue) in the origin post.